# Is it fair to use "protestant" as a synonym for "credobaptist"?

Tags: discussion, denominations, terminology

Is it fair to use "protestant" as a synonym for "credobaptist"?

I've noticed several instances here (both recent and historic) of folks using using "protestant" as a synonym for "denominations which practice [credobaptism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Believer%27s_baptism)"¹, i.e. [credobaptists](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/credobaptist). This seems disingenuous, as Wikipedia lists *several* major protestant denominations (what looks to me like a significant portion of them, perhaps even a majority) that practice [pædobaptism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infant_baptism)². In particular, IIUC, Lutherans (along with Catholics), who might be called "the original protestants", consider credobaptism a heresy.

In fact, AFAICT, the only "protestants" that practice CB are Baptists, the Churches of Christ, and possibly Pentacostals. Given that a *majority* of "protestants", at least counting the number of major denominations (and not members thereof) practice pædobaptism, it it fair to use "protestant" to refer to credobaptists? Or should we be discouraging this use, similar to how we discourage exclusion of LDSs and JWs from the SE?

(In fairness, population numbers *do* tell a different story, and in the U.S., Baptists are *easily* the majority of Protestants. Worldwide, however, the numbers aren't quite so skewed, and at best, equating "protestant" with "credobaptist" is probably offensive to *at least* a quarter of all protestants.)

(¹ a.k.a. believer's baptism; for this discussion, may be abbreviated CB or BB)

(² a.k.a. infant baptism; for this discussion, may be abbreviated PB or IB)

Answer (score 3):

No, of course not, and I can't remember seeing anyone here ever mistake the two. It's definitely not a common mistake.

The [major branches of Protestantism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protestantism#Major_branches) include:

- Credobaptist

  - Adventism
  - Anabaptist (Mennonites etc)
  - Baptists
  - Brethren
  - Churches of Christ
  - Pentecostalism
- Paedobaptist

  - Anglican
  - Continental Reformed
  - Lutheran
  - Methodism
  - Presbyterian

Answer (score -3):

No, I don't think so, and for that reason I preferred when we used "Reformed" instead of "Protestantism" because I think Evangelicals (even Evangelical Lutherans) fall under that moniker.  I was chatting with Curiousdannii and he wasn't of that mindset (that Evangelicals wouldn't consider themselves Protestants) but I don't know *any* Evangelicals who consider themselves Protestants in the normal sense.  They mostly avoid the nitpicks and tracts against the Catholic Church that Lutherans get taught in favor of either complete ignorance or something like passive ecumenism.

Of course, I don't know that many people, at least many non-Catholics who are actually religious, so my experience is limited.  I have been active on *this* site for a while though.  And I'm pretty sure that Evangelicals are Protestants only in the Bill Cosby sense that they say "Amen" in a cool way.

But this question isn't about Evangelicals of course, but I'm just trying to say that it's not a good idea to use Protestant as a synonym for ANYTHING.  Protestant means people who protest such and such a *practice* of the Catholic Church, not necessarily a belief.  In *protest* they *reformed* the doctrines of the Catholic Church making their own Churches (whereas the traditional way of reforming was to reform the practices of the Catholic Church).

So is some of the Churches reformed the doctrine of infant baptism and some didn't it wouldn't make sense to call credobaptists protestants, especially given the global nature of the site.

HOWEVER

with tagging, it is perfectly acceptable to use a tag that represents a subset of who the question is about if there is not a better more specific tag. And perfectly acceptable to use two tags even when the second one is entirely a subset of the first (as [credobaptism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credobaptism) would be for [protestant](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protestant).

Comment: You can't use "Reformed" to talk about Protestantism generally, because the Methodists, Lutherans(?), and majority of Credobaptists are Arminian. Only Anglican, Presbyterian, Continental Reformed, and the "Particular Baptists" have Reformed theology. The Evangelical/Liberal divide meanwhile cuts across all denominations. There are lots of Evangelical Arminians.

Comment: Are the Evangelicals you know personally devout, or is it just a cultural/political identity? (Like "Catholic" and "Protestant" in Northern Ireland.) I really don't understand why they wouldn't consider themselves Protestant, unless they basically don't know anything about Christianity. Sadly there are probably far too many people who would fit that.

Comment: @curious thanks for clarifying that with Reformed, I thought Lutherans fell under "reformed" but that was something I incorrectly picked up here.   The Evangelicals I'm talking about are very devout, non-denominational types.  They've got no particular beef with Rome.

Comment: "Reformed" isn't a great label, neither are "Catholic" or "Orthodox", but they're what we're stuck with now.

Comment: Agree with @curiousdannii  If I may add, a label is only as good as what it's used for: to make a distinction.  Depending on the purpose, the labels Protestant (vs. Catholic & Orthodox), Evangelicals (vs. liberals), Reformed (vs. other branches of Protestants) have their unique purpose and are NOT interchangeable.  That's why "Protestant Catholic" or "Lutheran Reformed" are oxymoron while "Evangelical Catholic" is meaningful, although rather rare.  "Evangelical Lutheran" is a historical mistake since they're liberal, see [my recent answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/85783/10672).

Comment: I hear Evangelical Catholic quite a bit, mainly because friends of ours lead https://www.evangelicalcatholic.org

Comment: @PeterTurner You meant Catholics who are active in the [New Evangelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_evangelization). But I was referring to a growing subset of Evangelical catholic (with a small "c") to mean Evangelical Protestants who maintain their "catholicity" in the sense of the historical ecumenical church before the split. See the various strands in this [wikipedia article section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelical_Catholic#Old_Catholicism,_Methodism,_and_Reformed_Christianity). I think I can call myself Evangelical catholic, which is a minority subset of evangelicals.